# how to get subcategory from productId in magento

Tags: php, magento

How to obtain a subcategory per product of identification?

I tried with mage :: getModel by the parent identifier but it does not suit me

I am using Magento 1.9

Sorry for my bad english

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
$_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;
echo $_cat->getName();
}
```